# Regarding arrays in c language

Tags: c

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lhr6p.png)

```
#include <stdio.h>

void fun(int arr[]) {
    int i;
    int arr_size = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);

    for (i =0;i<arr_size;i++)
        print("%d",arr[i]);
}

int main() {
    int i;
    int arr[4]= {10,20,30,40};
    fun(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone please explain me, if and how the size of array `sizeof(arr) = 4 & sizeof(arr\[0\]) = 4` becomes `arr_size = 2` ???
Please correct me. Thanks.

I tried to solve but I failed! If I'm missing something, guide with proper source for learning.

Comment: What is `arr`? What is `arr_size`? Please [edit] your question to show us a [mre].

Comment: Sure you posted the correct code? `sizeof(arr) = 4` makes no sense at all. It's not valid C code. Could it be that you wanted `sizeof(arr) == 4` ? In any case you need to provide more info

Comment: sorry I'm new here. I upload the screen short of the code is it visible for now although I'm trying to upload the code. Thanks for understanding.

Comment: @Kaustav Das The function parameter having an array type is implicitly converted to a pointer to the element type. In fact within the function you have sizeof( int * ) / sizeof( int ). And it seems sizeof( int * ) is equal to 8  and sizeof( int ) is equal to 4. As a result the value of the expression is 2.

Comment: OT: Don't know how `print()` is compiling for you. What happened to `printf()`?

Comment: opps !! it would be printf() Thanks

Comment: And [don't post images of code, data, error messages, etc.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)

Comment: As an argument, `int arr[]` is really the same as `int *arr`. That is, you have a pointer in the function. And the size of a pointer is the size of the actual pointer itself, the compiler doesn't keep track of what it might point to (because that could change at run-time). If you need a function to have the size of your array, you need to pass it as an argument.